# Java arguments from text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass arguments from a text file and perform the corresponding action on an object in java. I have the following thus far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Portfolio portfolio=new Portfolio();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0])).useDelimiter("\n");
            while(reader.hasNext()){
        String arg=reader.next();
        if(reader.hasNextInt()){
            int cash=reader.nextInt();
                      portfolio.arg(cash);
        }
        else if(reader.hasNext()){
            String ticker=reader.next();
            int shares=reader.nextInt();
            float price=reader.nextFloat();
              portfolio.arg(ticker,shares,price);
                    }
        portfolio.arg();
    }
    reader.close();


}
```

How can I pass the first as a method to the portfolio object, and the remaining as arguments for that method? Having a lot of trouble with this, thanks.

Comment: You're going to want to take a look [The Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I do not believe I am allowed to use such a thing.

Comment: How else do you expect to look up the method name dynamically?  The only other choice you have is a `if-else` statement, taking into consideration each method of `Portfolio`, but then you're going to have to check the arguments for correctness

Comment: @js7354 Why are you not allowed to use reflection?

Comment: @js7354, there seem to be some details missing that would be helpful to know.  It appears that the file contains a set of text strings that are used as arguments for a method in a Portfolio object and that the specific method to call is also specified as a text string.  So MadProgrammer does have a valid question, how are you going to map the method name text strings to actual methods in the Portfolio object along with the method arguments?

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for your response. I edited the code to give more of an idea of what I'm trying to do, the arguments would not be an issue, it's just getting the portfolio object to recognize arg as a method call.
The text file would be formatted like 
CASHIN 100000
BUY MSFT 20 32.24
where the Portfolio class has a CASHIN method, a BUY method, etc. I'm sorry if I'm not being very clear.

Comment: @RichardChambers this is exactly the question I'm trying to answer, the reflection API was never discussed in class, nor does it seem any other of my classmates are using it. Perhaps I'm structuring the entire project wrong, I'm not sure.

Comment: @js7354, if Portfolio has a know set of methods then you do not need to use Reflection since the methods are already known.  Instead you can use an if/else sequence to check the string of the method against the known list of methods in Portfolio object and to then pass the arguments which I suppose are all strings.  So what does the Portfolio class look like?

Comment: @RichardChambers It's basically just a linked list, with 2 nested classes including stock, which is basically a node class, and the iterator class. All classes work correctly if in my main method I simply call them regularly, just have an issue passing them from the file. I will do the branching if/else I suppose, I just assumed there was a more elegant solution. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @js7354: You should edit your question to amplify on this aspect of the problem.